# Flutter app slows significantly including the whole debugging in Visual studio code when tapped on a Text Input field

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

When running the app in debug mode in IOS simulator, app hangs (does not freeze but very slow and heavy) when I tap into a text form field (on focus). Looks like it's consuming a lot of memory and slowing the whole system down.
When I tap out of the field (on blur) things just go back to normal.
I am seeing this after upgrading SDK to 2.2.3.

**MacOSX**: BigSur 11.4

**XCode**: 12.5.1

**VS Code**:

```
    Version: 1.58.0
    Commit: 2d23c42a936db1c7b3b06f918cde29561cc47cd6
    Date: 2021-07-08T06:54:17.694Z (2 wks ago)
    Electron: 12.0.13
    Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
    Node.js: 14.16.0
    V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
    OS: Darwin x64 20.5.0
```

**Flutter SDK**: v 2.23

**pubsec.yaml**:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^5.0.0
  localstorage: ^3.0.0
  json_annotation: ">=4.0.1 <4.1.0"


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: "4.1.0"
  fab_circular_menu: ^1.0.0
  floating_action_bubble: 1.0.9
```

**Login screen input widgets:**

```
Widget _buildEmailTF(BuildContext contex) {
    final node = FocusScope.of(context);
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Email',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          height: 60.0,
          child: TextField(
            controller: usernameControlller,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            onEditingComplete: () => node.nextFocus(),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.email,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter your Email',
              hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPasswordTF(BuildContext contex) {
    final node = FocusScope.of(context);
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Password',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          height: 60.0,
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            controller: passwordControlller,
            onSubmitted: (_) {
              // node.unfocus();
              this.authenticateUser(context);
            },
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.lock,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter your Password',
              hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**Main Login Screen:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xFF73AEF5),
                      Color(0xFF61A4F1),
                      Color(0xFF478DE0),
                      Color(0xFF398AE5),
                    ],
                    stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 40.0,
                    vertical: 80.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      _buildEmailTF(context),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30.0,
                      ),
                      _buildPasswordTF(context),
                      _buildForgotPasswordBtn(),
                      _buildRememberMeCheckbox(),
                      _buildLoginBtn(),
                      _buildSignInWithText(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an issue with your Code (It happens to me as well when having heavily decorated TextFields).

But you can still try this to go sure:

`flutter run --release`

This will run your app in release mode. If it is still slow it means there is a problem with your code propably.